# rule validation not triggered on input field when value is changed from React state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have an input text field that's required on a form. When I edit the field manually and set it to the empty string the validation rule triggers and the message does indeed show up. When I empty the field via React state (e.g. using a button), the validation rule is not triggered.
Sandbox is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-leftpad-7t350?file=/src/App.js). For completeness purposes, code is also given below:

```
import React from 'react';
import {  Form, Input, Button } from 'antd';


class FormExample extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {fields: [{name: 'field-a', value: 42}]}
  }
  
  emptyField = () => {
    this.setState({fields:[{name: 'field-a', value: null}]});
  }
  
  render() {
    const rules = [{ required: true, message: 'the field is required!' }];
      return (
        <>
          <Button onClick={this.emptyField}>emptyField</Button>
          <Form
            name="global_state"
            layout="inline"
            fields={this.state.fields}
          >
            <Form.Item
              label={'The answer is: '}
              name={'field-a'}
              rules={rules}>
              <Input disabled={false}/>
            </Form.Item>
          </Form>
        </>
      );
  }
}


export default FormExample;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

You need to add a `validateFields` to your antd [FormInstance](https://ant.design/components/form/#FormInstance)

E.g.: `this.formRef.current.validateFields()`

---

**Long answer:**

As described in the antd [FormItem](https://ant.design/components/form/#Form.Item) docs, you should not use `setState` instead use `setFieldsValue`.

> You shouldn't call setState manually, please use form.setFieldsValue
> to change value programmatically.

An example how to use Form method with Class Component can be found in this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xx42x).

E.g.:

```
  emptyField = () => { 
    this.formRef.current.setFieldsValue({"field-a": null})
    this.formRef.current.validateFields()
  };
```

Additional you can use `resetFields` instead of setting the value to `null`.

E.g.:

```
  emptyField = () => { 
    this.formRef.current.resetFields()
    this.formRef.current.validateFields()
  };
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-sound-g6fhf) is the complete example:

```
import React from "react";

import { Form, Input, Button } from "antd";

class FormExample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { fields: [{ name: "field-a", value: 42 }] };
  }

  formRef = React.createRef();

  emptyField = () => { 
    // this.formRef.current.setFieldsValue({"field-a": null})
    this.formRef.current.resetFields()
    this.formRef.current.validateFields()
  };

  render() {
    const rules = [{ required: true, message: "the field is required!" }];
    return (
      <>
        <Button onClick={this.emptyField}>emptyField</Button>
        <Form ref={this.formRef} name="global_state" layout="inline" fields={this.state.fields}>
          <Form.Item label={"The answer is: "} name={"field-a"} rules={rules}>
            <Input disabled={false} />
          </Form.Item>
        </Form>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default FormExample;
```

Comment: I cannot accept this answer as it is too imperative. In my real app I am using Redux to store the state of my application and it would seem to me that such an imperative approach goes against the Redux model. Up-voted since it helped me find the right answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/63072264/274677)

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63070365/274677) by [zerocewl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10036039/zerocewl) presents an imperative approach which I didn't want to follow as I am using Redux to store the state of my application (even though for this short, self-contained example, to keep things simple, I am using local component state). However, I used the `validateFields()` API presented in his answer, initially as follows:

```
componentDidUpdate = (prevProps: any, prevState: any) => {
    this.formRef.current.validateFields();
}
```

For some reason, the above code wasn't working. The below code however does work and that's all that was necessary. I.e. field values are propagated directly from the Redux store - there are no `resetFields` or `setFieldsValue` calls.

```
componentDidUpdate = (prevProps: any, prevState: any) => {
    setTimeout(()=>{this.formRef.current.validateFields()}, 0);
}
```

I cannot explain why the above code works while the fully synchronous version does not.